# WPF invoke method when model property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, model, binding

It is a problem that I face for a long time.

Let say that we have a POCO class called Person (INotifyPropertyChanged is provided using Foldy and its [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface] attribute)

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class Person
{ 
        public int Id{ get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field required")]
        public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

And in ViewModel I reference this class as a Property

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   public Person Person
   {
      get => person;
      set
      {
          person= value;
          SomeMethod();
      }
   }
// Rest of the code
}
```

And question is how can I invoke "SomeMethod" when first name is changed in textbox.

Textbox is bound to property as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged)/>
```

I tried to work around it binding to:

```
 public string FirstName
 {
   get => firstName;
   set
      {
        firstName= value;
        Person.FirstName=value;
        SomeMethod();
      }
 }
```

But the problem is with validation in the user form because I use data annotation attributes in POCO class for validation.

Thank you in advance for your help and your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, there are 2 options for you to achieve what you want:

1. Create a view model for Person and move you method to the setter for FirstName. Bind the Textbox to the FirstName property of PersonViewModel and SomeMethod() will be invoked whenver you change texts in TextBox.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set 
        {
            _firstName = value;
            SomeMethod();
        }
}
```

2. In some cases you must implement SomeMethod() inside the owner ViewModel, then just use the interactivity to bind to TextChanged event of the Textbox and assign you method as invoke method.

```xml
xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<TextBox Name="your_textBox" Text={Binding ...}>
    <i:Interactivity.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Commmand="{Binding YourMethodInViewModel, ElementName=your_textbox}", CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=your_textbox}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interactivity.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

```
public ICommand YourMethodInViewModel{get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction - the solution was so close :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to listen to property changes of `Person`:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Person = new Person();
  }

  public Person Person
  {
    get => this.person;
    set
    { 
      if (this.Person != null)
      {
        this.Person.PropertyChanged -= OnPersonFirstNameChanged;
      }

      this.person= value;

      if (this.Person != null)
      {
        this.Person.PropertyChanged += OnPersonFirstNameChanged;
      }        
    }
  }

  public void OnPersonFirstNameChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Person.FirstName))
    {
      SomeMethod();
    }      
  }
}
```

Alternatively implement a `Person.FirstNameChanged` event that `Person` can raise. This improves readability. `PropertyChanged` is intended primarily for the data binding engine. Since you have to switch on `PropertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyChanged` in order to find out what happened, you can't handle this event gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @Thế Long who pointed me to the right direction, for those who faced the same problem - I used "SourceUpdated" event in order to be able to set delay in binding
[msdn SourceUpdated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated?view=netcore-3.1)

```
xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<TextBox Text={Binding = " ..., Delay=500"}>
    <i:Interactivity.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SourceChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Commmand="{Binding SomeMethodCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interactivity.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```